# How to solve" Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C2."

Tags: google-sheets

Fomula that works:

[image: Fomula that works]

Fomula that doesn't work:

[image: Fomula that doesn't work]

Hi guys, I encounter a problem.
I use the Inventory template from sheetgo.

I copy the fomula that works and paste it on another sheet.
Unfortunately, it got an error with the arrayfomula.

I have spent a long time investigating all possibilities but still can't solve them.

Is any expert able to help in this matter?

Answer (score 1):

error says it all... in order to expand the results of arrayformula you need to clear range C2:C so that arrayformula could roll out. also, it looks like your formula is wrong but hard to tell for certain because you did not include a copy of your sheet nor formula

Comment: thanks for your comment.

I found out something weird now.

i try to make a copy of the google sheet.

and that fomula works

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when it is attached connection in Sheetgo.

WHY!